# Magento 2.4.3 PWA Venia : Add to Cart is not working

Tags: pwa-studio, magento2.4.3, venia

I successfully installed venia on my localhost system.
When I create a customer and logged in to my customer account and then try to add to cart a product , then in Browser Console I am getting the below message

`[GraphQL error]: Message: Cannot query field "enable_multiple_wishlists" on type "StoreConfig"., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined`

[image]

I am using Magento 2.4.3 on Ubuntu 21.04, localhost machine

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Comment: I am also facing the same issue [GraphQL error]: Message: Cannot query field "enable_multiple_wishlists" on type "StoreConfig"., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined I am using Magento 2.4.3 on Ubuntu 21.04, localhost machine Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3):

In packages\venia-concept .env

Change the value to MOS, multiple_wishlists should be only EE feature

```
MAGENTO_BACKEND_EDITION=MOS
```

---

but there is another bug arise, and you can see in exception log

---

```
graph-ql-6253d559e7f2b; Message: Config element "ProductAttributeMetadata" is not declared in GraphQL schema {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: graph-ql-6253d559e7f2b; Message: Config element \"ProductAttributeMetadata\" is not declared in GraphQL schema at /var/www/magento-pwa/magento/vendor/magento/framework/GraphQl/Exception/ExceptionFormatter.php:59, LogicException(code: 0): Config element \"ProductAttributeMetadata\" is not declared in GraphQL schema at /var/www/magento-pwa/magento/vendor/magento/framework/GraphQl/Config.php:57)"} []
```

after that, you can search "aux" in config.php,

enable such modules, so you should able to add products in cart now.

Comment: I have enabled those modules and that error is gone , Magento_CatalogGraphQlAux, Magento_EavGraphQlAux

Answer (score 0):

**Just enable these modules by running below commands:**

```
php bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Magento_EavGraphQlAux Magento_CatalogGraphQlAux Magento_PageBuilderPwa Magento_ReCaptchaGraphQlPwa Magento_ReCaptchaPwa Magento_SalesGraphQlAux Magento_UrlRewriteGraphQlPwa Magento_WeeeGraphQlAux
```